# My app post data into JSON however it also throws this error "http://localhost:5000/write net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, axios

Sorry if I don't post the correct details, this is my first hands-on project after going through online tutorials.

I'm using React, node with axios to build a web app that captures status(available, in a meeting, lunch etc) and the time spent on each status.

The app works fine, it captures and writes the data onto the backend(JSON) however, I keep getting this error on the console.

1. POST https://localhost:5000/write net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
2. Uncaught (in promise) ERROR: Network Error

[image]

I've tried to look for a solution but can't find one that is similar to the tech-stack I used. Also, my lack of sufficient knowledge don't help either.

Any lead or read or solution will help.

pasting my code below:
My frontend code to push data into JSON file

```
const saveJson = (posts) => {
//api URL //end point from node server / express server
const url = "http://localhost:5000/write";
axios.post(url, posts).then((response) => {
  //console.log(response);
}); };
```

The server.js code

```
    const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

//calling packages
const fs = require("fs");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");

//Declare app
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

//middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(cors());

//default route for server
app.get("/", (req, res) =>
  res.status(200).send({
    message: "Server is running...",
  })
);

const WriteTextToFileAsync = async (contentToWrite) => {
  fs.writeFile("./src/data.json", contentToWrite, (err) => {
    console.log(contenToWrite);
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Done writing to file...");
      // res.json({ msg: "success" });
    }
  });
};

//Declare timerow/write route to accept incoming require with data
app.post("/write", async (req, res, next) => {
  //take the body from incoming requestby using req.body and conver it into string
  const requestContent = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  await WriteTextToFileAsync(requestContent);
});

//404 route for server
app.use((req, res, next) =>
  res.status(404).send({
    message: "Could not find specified route requested...!",
  })
);

//run server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(
    `!!! server is running
     !!! Listening for incoming requests on port ${port}
     !!! http://localhost:5000
    `
  );
});
```

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem" Error text rarely summarizes the problem sufficiently. Also, images of text are not helpful to people with vision problems, nor to search engines, since neither can read text in images.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've edited my post and written the errors. But like I wrote, I'm new and with the lack of knowledge, I really don't know what is the error about.  My app works, there is no problem with that, its just that the console throws the error message and I want to understand why. I tried but could not get why its happening.